# Date Of birth in drupal

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I am newer in Drupal. I am using Drupal services. I want to insert user birthdate by Drupal rest services. I want How we do this, Any help would be appericiated. Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the  [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) module

> This package contains both a flexible date/time field type Date field and a Date API that other modules can use.

Comment: url for this....

Comment: Click on that Date. I've provided module URL already. Here again
https://www.drupal.org/project/date